# React Native changing Bottom Tab Navigator color dynamically

Tags: react-native, redux, darkmode

I have one question about React Native. I'm using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` package to have bottom navigation. Today I implemented a dark mode changer for my app.
I have one problem with `<Tab.Navigator>`. Problem is that every color option is defined inside `screenOptions`. Is it possible to pass props and change colors based on the theme selected by the user?

Let me show you what I need.
When I have dark mode enabled, the whole app looks like this:
[image: Dark mode]

When I set light mode, the app looks like this:
[image: Light mode]

I just need to change the bottom bar color to white and icons to black in light mode.
Is it even possible?

My code is here:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function MainContainer(){
    const theme = useSelector((state) => state.themeReducer.theme);
    return(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName={skolboz}
            screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    let iconName;
                    let rn = route.name;

                    if (rn === skolboz) {
                        iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'
                    } else if (rn === newCase){
                        iconName = focused ? 'add' : 'add-outline'
                    } else if (rn === settings){
                        iconName = focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline'
                    }
                    
                    return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
                },
                "tabBarActiveTintColor": "orange",
                "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "#FFF",
                "tabBarActiveBackgroundColor": "#000",
                "tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor": "#000",
                "tabBarLabelStyle": {
                  "fontSize": 10
                },
                "tabBarStyle": [
                    {
                      "display": "flex",
                      "borderTopWidth": 0,
                      "backgroundColor": "#000"
                    },
                    null
                  ],
                "headerStyle": [
                    {
                        "backgroundColor": "orange",
                    }
                ],
              })}
            >

                <Tab.Screen name={skolboz} component={Skolboz} options={{headerTitle: 'SKOLBOZ', headerTintColor: "white"}} />
                <Tab.Screen name={newCase} component={NewCase} options={{headerTitle: 'Pridať nový nedostatok', headerTintColor: "white"}} />
                <Tab.Screen name={settings} component={Settings} options={{headerTitle: 'Nastavenia', headerTintColor: "white"}} />

            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

I'm using redux to change color based on the theme of the app. Passing props like this:

```
${props => props.theme.PRIMARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR};
```

How can I do the same logic inside `screenOptions`?

Thank you all for your reply!

Comment: Ok I fixed this issue. I'm checking if theme is light or dark and display tabs based on that.